# Почему [unixODBC][Driver Manager] не видит библиотеку sqlanywhere12 в /opt если путь в php существует

Tags: php, sql, ubuntu, apache2, odbc

Увага! SQLSTATE[01000] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/sqlanywhere12/lib64/libdbodbc12.so' : file not found

Были ещё прописанны такие данные:

```
     - sudo nano /etc/apache2/envvars
    **add to file**
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:/opt/sqlanywhere12/lib64:/opt/sqlanywhere12/lib32: 
    export SQLANY12=/opt/sqlanywhere12 
    export ODBCINI=/etc/odbc.ini

 - sudo nano  /ect/apache2/apache2.conf add in the end file ServerName projectName

 - sudo nano  /ect/apache2/apache2.conf in direction /var/www add permission AllowOverride All


- sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/project.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName projectName

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/projectName

SetEnv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /opt/sqlanywhere12/lib64:/opt/sqlanywhere12/lib32
SetEnv ODBCINI /etc/odbc.ini
SetEnv SQLANY12 /opt/sqlanywhere12


    <Directory /var/www/html/projectName>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Require all granted
   
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/project_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/project_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

- sudo nano /etc/odbcinst.ini
 =>
[Sybase12] 
Description=SQL Anywhere 12 
Driver=/opt/sqlanywhere12/lib64/libdbodbc12.so 
Setup=/opt/sqlanywhere12/lib64/libdbodbc12.so 
UsageCount=1 
TDS_Version = 5


- sudo nano /etc/odbc.init
=>
    [asvioDB] 
*данные для подключения к бд*
Driver=Sybase12
```